# Msgraph-sdk-java vs Msgraph-sdk-android for Android?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Has anyone tried Android development using Microsoft Graph SDKs? 
What is the preferred SDK for Android? There are two SDKs available - one for Java (msgraph-sdk-java) and one separately for Android (msgraph-sdk-android) and its very confusing to choose between two. No appropriate documentation available as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion Samhith.  We are in the process of deprecating the [Android](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-android) SDK in favour of the [Java](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java) SDK for Android.  The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=Android#interactive-provider) here should have mentioned the correct configuration for using Java.  That's on me to fix.

There is an example of creating a client for Android [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-client?tabs=Android) but you are absolutely correct that the guidance is not clear. 
There is a dedicated Android Authorization Prodvider that can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-android-auth).

All future work will be in the Java SDK and we will support the Android platform via that SDK.

Comment: Thanks a lot Darrel, that helps!